# WooCommerce get all products with SKU

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get a list of products with sku and post id with this code, everything seems fine and ok with this code :

```
$statuses = array('publish', 'draft');

// Args on the main query for WC_Product_Query
$args = [
    'status'    => $statuses,
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'limit'     => -1,
];

$vendor_products = wc_get_products($args);

$list_array = array();

foreach ($vendor_products as $key => $product) {

    if ($product->get_type() == "variable") {

        // Args on product variations query for a variable product using a WP_Query
        $args2 = array( 
            'post_parent' => $product->get_id(), 
            'post_type'   => 'product_variation', 
            'orderby'     => array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC' ), 
            'fields'      => 'ids', 
            'numberposts' => -1, 
        ); 

        foreach ( get_posts( $args2 ) as $child_id ) {
            // get an instance of the WC_Variation_product Object
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); 

            if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() ) {
                continue;
            }

            $list_array[] = array(
                'sku'      => $variation->get_sku(),
                'postid'   => $variation->get_id()
            );
        }

    } else {

        $list_array[] = array(
            'sku'      => $product->get_sku(),
            'postid'   => $product->get_id()
        );

    }
}
```

I have total 1660 (470 published and 1,190 drafted) products but it's just returns 501 products and i don't know why!
this is my products in woocommerce:
[image]

this is the final result of query :
[image]

this is the result of Janki's code
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // Woocommerce get all products
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => array('product','product_variation'),
    'meta_key'   => '_sku',
    'post_status' => array('publish','draft'), 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
       
$products = new WP_Query($args);
 
    /* using this code you can get all products */
    /* this may help you to get details */
```

Comment: This code works but i need SKU of products and product variations, i don't know how to get them

Comment: i have updated code so can you please try this to resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you, 'post_type' => ''product_variation',',   only ?? is this right ?

Comment: post_type is only product_variation , is this code gives me product and product variations?

Comment: you can use array also for multiple type

Comment: Done, updated the question and please take a look at the result of WP_QUERY, what to do with it now ?

Comment: this is your result array so now you just need to process your data in while loop

Comment: how we handle any WP_Query result

Comment: I'm confused now,  can u help me a little bit ? how to get postid and sku from this result ?

Comment: // The Product Query
$products= new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        // Your code here
    endwhile;

} else {
        // no posts found
}

Comment: wrote this code, at the end print_r($products->the_post()) returns nothing,

Comment: i think you are not familiar with WP_Query wordpress function , i suggest you to cont. on your above stuff from woocommerce function directly

Comment: All done, I can get both sku and post id, but all i have is 10 result, i set 'numberposts' and 'limit' to -1 to get all of them but i just get 10 result

Comment: good to hear you positive answer.  if you resolved this question then please mark as resolved

Comment: Yes , with WP_Query, how to get all of the products ? it's just return me 10 result

Comment: instead of limit you can you 'posts_per_page' => '-1', also

Comment: there is one thing more, I'm preparing data and sending them wp_remote_post to Laravel api, but wp_remote_post just sends 1000 data instead of 1631 data. do you have any idea ?